# how to use MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialog to create a messagebox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create notification before closing a form on WPF c#. But after clicking the Close Button on the Form, it will close the form without notifying the user. Can someone help me to do this. Thank you. This is my code.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
        private async void frmMain_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string msg = "Do you want to exit this application?";
                Classes.DialogService dS = new Classes.DialogService();
                MessageDialogResult dr = await dS.ShowMessage(msg, MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, "Exit Application");
                if (dr == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
                {
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Class:

```
    using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
    using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace AttendanceMngt.Classes
    {
        class DialogService
        {
            public  async Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowMessage( string message, MessageDialogStyle dialogStyle)
            {
                var metroWindow = (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
                metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented;
                return await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(
                    "MY TITLE", message, dialogStyle, metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions);
            }
        }    
    }
```

Thank you and regards

Comment: In which method of MainWindow.xaml.cs do you run your code?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , in frmMain_Closing sir.

Comment: Please, update the question and share it. It should be an `async` as well

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , I updated the part sir. please see it

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , Hello Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the solution I had created.

I just set the `e.Cancel = true` for the execution of the code inside the class. After that. It will show the message and ask the user if they really wanted to close the application.

If there is a better solution than this, Please Tell me. For now, I will use this as the Solution. Thank you and Regards.

```
    private async void frmMain_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            string msg = "Do you want to exit this application?";
            Classes.DialogService dS = new Classes.DialogService();
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageDialogResult dr = await dS.ShowMessage(msg, MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, "Exit Application");
            if (dr == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative){
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```